# What is included in URI character limit

Tags: http

When we say URI has a character limit of 255 characters, is 'http://' or 'https://' also included while counting characters?
I tried to google it, but couldn't find a definite answer.

Comment: you probably mean URI. URL has ~2000 char limit

Answer (score 0):

`http://` and `https://` are *not* included in the URI length limit of 255 (of some older client or proxy implementations).
Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381792/url-getting-truncated-at-255-characters) and personal experience/knowledge (couldn't find any *formal* ref).