# URL is getting truncated at different places

Tags: http, post, get, request, jsonp

We're facing a strange issue where our HTTP requests are getting truncated randomly. I checked out this question on [URL getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381792/url-getting-truncated-at-255-characters) , but I wasn't sure whether this is what was happening. The problem is that the requests from the same User Agent are getting truncated in different places, so it's hard to detect which browsers are causing this. Now, is there any possible fix other than changing the GET requests to POST requests?

If POST requests are the way to go for the fix, we use JSONP for our form submissions. Knowing that POST doesn't work with JSONP, what would be my best option to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching to using POST with CORS enabling.